# OpenSSL Digital Signature with ES256

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, hashing, json

I am trying to reproduce a valid signature for the JSON Web Token.

I make the privat key with: **openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out private.pem**
also convert this from Pem to P8 with: **openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in private.pem -out privateKey.p8**

The unsigned Token, which is the header and payload in Base64Url.

If I make my Signature with:
**openssl dgst -sha256 -sign -privateKey.p8 -out signature.sha256 unsignedToken.txt** and then make it Base64 like: **openssl base64 -in signature.sha256**

I dont get a valid signature, and also the valid Signature has to be 86 Characters. In my case I get 96 Character and every Signature is starting with 'ME'.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like some form of ASN.1 wrapping. 1) Can you post quick instructions for generating a compatible private key? 2) Can you check with `openssl asn1parse -in signature.sha256 -i` whether it contains a field with the "real" signature inside?

Comment: If I try asn1parse i got the 'Error: offset out of range'